# Taking input for distance calculation

Tags: python

I have to make a program to calculate the distance between two points but I want it to be more good, I want the program should take input like this 
Enter two value for first distance:(2,2) I want to take inputs 2 numbers but in brackets and a comma between them, Thank you.

```
while True:
    try:
        x1,x2 =int(input(f"Enter two value for first distance:")).split()
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease enter only number distance points")
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        y1,y2 =int(input("Enter two value for second distance:")).split()
    except ValueError:
        print("\nPlease enter only number")
    else:
        break

import math
distance = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2))
```

Comment: Why do you have two while loops? You could just have one while loop and input both the values, as a start.

Comment: please put the import statements in the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works for two float numbers separated by commas. This will work whether surrounding brackets parentheses are included or not, so this will work for `2, 2` as well as `(2, 2)` or `[2, 2]`. Note that this will also work for `[2, 2)` and `(2, 2`, which you may or may not want.

```
x1, x2 = (float(v) for v in input(
    'Enter two values separated by commas for the first point: '
).strip('[( )]').split(','))
```